# core text CTFontGetBoundingRectsForGlyphs() is to slow

Tags: cocoa, core-text

I am using CTFontGetBoundingRectsForGlyphs() to find single glyphs width.
But it is too slow to call it multiple times per text line. And I ask you is there faster method to check glyph dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CTFontGetAdvancesForGlyphs()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/1511265-ctfontgetadvancesforglyphs) may be a faster way to find a single glyphs width.

Alternatively, if you're using `CTLine` and `CTRun`, then [`CTRunGetAdvances()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/1510488-ctrungetadvances) and [`CTRunGetAdvancesPtr()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/1508625-ctrungetadvancesptr) should give faster results as they're returning cached values.